# В "Тихом Доне" черти водятся?

Tags: литература, история

Часто встречал мнение, что на самом деле "Тихий Дон" Шолохова не является его произведение. И существует какое-то другое произведение, которое писатель выдал за своё.

Насколько верны эти сведения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дискуссия на эту тему ведется много десятилетий. Особенно остро она велась в 60-е годы, когда Шолохову присудили Нобелевскую премию за роман "Тихий Дон". Чаще всего упоминается писатель Ф.Крюков, у которого будто бы Шолохов "позаимствовал" текст романа. Однако шведские ученые путем компьютерного лингвистического анализа текста установили, что "Тихий Дон" и более ранние, а также более поздние произведения Шолохова написаны одним и тем же человеком.

Answer (score 4):

Откуда Ф. Крюков мог знать, что командиром максаевской повстанческой сотни был Богатырёв?! Беседовал ли он хоть раз с Харлампием Ермаковым, или с Павлом Кудиновым, или с кем-то из заметных  участников Вёшенского восстания, чтобы описать в подробности ход тогдашних событий? Это предположение не совместимо с реальностью ни в пространстве, ни во времени. Да, молодость Шолохова и его слабый образовательный ценз (а разве у Пушкина и Горького он был выше?!) могут вызвать (да и вызывают!) сомнения в возможности человека написать ТАКОЙ (редкостный по эпичности и художественной выразительности) роман. Но мы же все люди простые. Как можно с нашей незамысловатой колокольни судить гения: Моцарта, Эйнштейна, Шолохова?.. Поразительно, но даже такие писатели, как Набоков, Бунин, Солженицын - и те запятнали себя сомнениями.  Чего же требовать от Доброва?.. А Горький сказал о первом томе "Тихого Дона":"Анафемски талантлива наша Русь"... Этот роман читали: Набоков, Бунин, Солженицын, Горький.  Я тоже читал его. Почему я понимаю Горького, не имевшего лауреатского звания, но не понимаю сомнений трёх названных Нобелевских лауреатов? Извините: сам не знаю!.. Шолохов такой роман МОГ написать! - даже Добров с этим согласен. Психика всех гениев сдвинута по фазе, но если бы не они, мы ещё сидели бы в пещерах и, наевшись мяса, танцевали бы вокруг костра: "Ба-бу-бы! Ба-бу-бы!"

Comment: Браво. Сочинение на тему "Как я провел летом бабушку" Вы написали блестяще. А кроме эмоций что есть? 
ЗЫ При всем уважении сравнение Шолохова с Эйнтейном представляется несколько опрометчивым.

Comment: "...провёл..." - это как? Обманул? Надул? Или "провёл через немецкие посты"? За оценку сочинения спасибо.Кроме эмоций, есть много фактического материала - целые тома пртиворечивых мнений, в которых эмоций - ноль! А вопросы всё поднимаются. Почему же люди с противоположными мнениями не находят взаимопонимания? Потому что ими правят эмоции. Поэтому и мне -  простительно... Шолохов - Эйштейн. Я сравниваю не интеллекты обоих, а впечатление от созданного ими. Шолохов - Л. Толстой - менее опрометчиво, но очень спорно,поскольку слишком много судей. "Война и мир" - "Тихий Дон" - всё другое.

Comment: русак, это шутка была.
А Вы хотите серьезного обсуждения после Вашей обличительной речи ни о чем?!  
Ну так я могу сказать.  
Вопрос об истинности предположений о плагиате я поднимать не хотел вообще. Ибо если человек просит его ознакомить с проблемой, то доказывать ему что-то заранее становясь на чью-то сторону - не комильфо.   
Но если так Вы хотите серьезно поспорить на конкретную тему, то изВольте.
Начнем с того, какой тезис Вы собираетесь доказывать - и на основании чего?!

Comment: У меня никогда не возникала мысль о том, что можно украсть целых четыре тома у кого-то. Долгое время я вообще не знал, что Шолохова обвиняли в плагиате. А когда узнал - удивился, что такое можно подумать.Я рос в той среде, где говорили на языке "Тихого Дона", первая песня, которую я услышал от матери, это: "Колода-дуда, Иде ж ты была..." (она приводится в "ТД"). Ф. Крюков не из наших мест, вряд ли он эту песню слышал - если уж Шолохову противопоставляют Крюкова!(Понимаю, что это - не довод)... Для основательного спора у меня нет базы, да и не хочется.Тезис: автор "ТД" - Шолохов, и никто иной.

Comment: >У меня никогда не возникала мысль о том, что можно украсть целых четыре тома у кого-то.  
  
Это единственный аргумент? 
Ну так никто и не коворит а) о краже, б) о всех четырех томах.
Т.е. получается Вы яростно спорите с тезисом, которого не знаете. Т.е. с самим собой. 
Речь как правило идет о существовании "протографа" - рукописи, покрывающей примерно треть романа - лучшие главы первых двух томов. Эта рукопись было сильно переработана, но сохранила характерные признаки, не свойственные ни остальному тексту, ни другим произведениям Шолохова. Конечно, сумасшествием можно объяснить все.

Comment: О какой рукописи Вы ведёте речь: о той, что Шолохов перед войной отдал на хранение Кудашёву? Или о той таинственной («протографе» предполагаемого Ф. Крюкова), которую Шолохов «дорабатывал», приступая к своему роману? Я читал отрывки из Крюкова – там Шолоховым и не пахнет! Скучно, натуралистично - ни взлёта, ни блеска… Интересно, а «Войне и миру» не искали «протографа»? Наверняка, он есть!.. Теперь Серафимовича нет? Медведицкая? Даже не Усть-? "Колода-дуда" - уверен! - пелась только в наших благословенных местах! Усть-Медведицкие матери на сочинение такой песни не способны (ЗЫ)

Comment: >О какой рукописи Вы ведёте речь  
  
Я? Я не веду. Я излагаю соображения сторонников существования протографа и стараюсь взвешенно передать их. А они, сторонники, ведут речь о гипотетической рукописи, которой (предположительно) пользовался Шолохов при написании как минимум первых двух томов "ТД".   
Касательно кто там кому отдавал, я, не будучи спецом, не совсем в курсе. Это имеет какое-то отношение к вопросу авторства? 

>...там Шолоховым и не пахнет!  
Я читал и то и другое. Давно, правда. Сравнивал ТД с Ш. и К. Крюкова в первых томах больше. Личное мнение.

Comment: Итак, существовала рукопись неизвестного автора (предположительно - Ф. Крюкова), которою пользовался Шолохов при написании всемирно известного романа. Крюков помог Шолохову только в двух первых томах  (к великому сожалению читателей - только в двух!! Потому что вторые два тома оказались слабее, бледнее  первых двух. Это объясняется тем, что Крюков умер, а Шолохов постарел, иссяк. Да и вообще - он был, по Доброву, туповатый деревенский воришка). Всё остальное, написанное Шолоховым, - н-ну, как бы это сказать? - недостойно имени Шолохова + Крюков... Личное Ваше мнение я уважаю, но не могу согла

Answer (score 3):

Они... как бы это сказать... не лишены аргументации.
Прежде всего давайте договоримся, что считать "другое произведение" и "выдал за свое". 
В отношении Шолохова термин "плагиат" явно неприменим. Есть рукописи, по ним видна работа над текстом, юридически тоже - не подкопаешься.

Таким образом, речь может идти (и идет) о существовании т.н. протографа - рукописи другого автора, которая была доступна автору обсуждаемого произведения и была положена в основу канонического текста.

Для выявления такого протографического источника выполняется т.н. текстологическая экспертиза, которая по анализу структуры предложений, словника, общей схемы подачи текста и проч. предложений позволяет, помимо прочего, установить наличие подобных заимствований - и степень их адаптированности к остальной части авторского теста. 
Такая экспертиза проводилась неоднократно, в целом результаты не слишком совпадают, но наличие сильно переработанного протографа в общем-то не оспаривается.

Называется и конкретный автор - Федор Крюков.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2
(смотрите в списке - на букву Ф).

Кроме того доводы сторонников "заимствования" основываются на "косвенных уликах", связанных с биографией Шолохова, анализом других произведений Шолохова и авторов предполагаемых "первоисточников" (версия Крюкова не единственная) и отношением их к предмету и событиям.

Говорю только о фактах без их оценки. Брать на себя роль судьи и тем более занимать чью-то позицию - не хочу. Мне вся эта история, коль скора пока она не выходит за пределы просто большой склоки, интересна тем, что протографические изыскания позволяют отчасти восстановить исходный текст и лучше понять спорные и противоречивые места "ТД".

Если же интересны подробности, вот здесь апофеоз контр-апологетики Шолохова.
http://www.dm-dobrov.ru/publicism/don/
Удивляет, правда, что автор даже не упоминает о многочисленных текстологических экспертизах, даже тех, что вполне в духе его гипотез и выводов. Вроде как он один, кто  все лучше всех знает.

Answer (score 3):

Насчёт Крюкова - бред полнейший. Так могут рассуждать только совершенно безграмотные люди, не обладающие чувством языка. Крюков - третьестепенный беллетрист, что не умаляет его достаточно скромного места в истории русской литературы. Шолохов (абстрагируясь от того, кто скрывался под этой фамилией) - гений. Гений абсолютный. Язык его произведений - неподражаем. Критики Шолохова убого пытаются убедить публику, будто бы два последних тома ТД - слабее первых. Однако это - бред собачий. Достаточно просто взять и прочесть. Самое страшное - НИКТО из критиков не читал роман! Он в нём только ковырялся.

Гениальна и "Поднятая целина", написанная тем же автором. ОДНИМ УНИКАЛЬНЫМ АВТОРОМ. Шолохов в большей степени даже не писатель, а поэт. Достаточно прочесть его описания природы, людей, характеров...

Донские рассказы, ТД, ПЦ - писаны ОДНИМ И ТЕМ ЖЕ АВТОРОМ. Этого оспорить невозможно.

Comment: Ну, Сидоров, Вы даете. ))
Ну ладно, вопрос о "ТД" для Вас слишком сложен, но отсавивать гениальность отвратительного антиказачьего пасквиля под названием "Поднятая целина" методом заглавных букв - это круто... 
 
Нет, Сидоров, все-таки это я с Вами тогда на Грамоте ругался...  
Безапеляционность, беспардонность и беспонтовость суждений видна  нефооруженным злазом

Comment: @Сидоров-Жиганец! @behemothus-ов убедить невозможно! У них отсутствует не только приёмник радиоволн, но и элементарное понимание красоты в литературе. Они запрограммированы на скушное существование в нашем грешном мире, подглядывание в чужие замочные скважины и рассуждения "с учёным видом знатока" о том, что им понять не под силу в виду своей запрограммированности на антидобро. Казак @behemothus принародно только что высек себя, назвав ПЦ отвратительным антиказачьим пасквилем. Он же неисправим! Прости его, Господи, за то, что не ведает, что говорит. Просвети его, несчастного раба Божьего!

Comment: >@Сидоров-Жиганец! @behemothus-ов убедить невозможно!   
  
Да! Даже если Вы всеми мультами Дерзкого начнете это делать, у Вас не прибавится ни аргументов, ни полемических приемов, ни весомости.   
Потому что кроме крика и сознания собственной правоты себя любимого надо иметь еще кое-сто за пазухой. 
Ну например - не замыкаться на убеждении бегемотусов всеми законными и противозаконными средствами, а найти кого-нибудь более подходящего для отправления ваших естественных потребностей спорить ради спора. Честь имею, раздухарившиеся клоники!

Comment: ЗЫ Хотя и правда пора мотать отсюда. 
Количество мультов Дерзкого уже превысило все мыслимые границы.   
Спорить огромной армией клонотроллей - это уже становится не смешно.
Ну хоть бы видимость различного подхода к аргументации соблюдали.   
А то все как под копирку... И плюсики лепят друг другу...


//=========  
Все последние откровения на тему ТД, бычков, Улан-удэнского и протсая и протчая и прочтчая...   
>... писаны ОДНИМ И ТЕМ ЖЕ АВТОРОМ. Этого оспорить невозможно.

Comment: ЗЫ! Ради Бога, не мотайте отсюда! Не бойтесь Дерзкого, он только на словах дерзкий, а по сути - добрейшей души человек. Вы же очень эрудированный господин. Ваши рассуждения, касающиеся русского языка и исторических параллелей  языкознания, довольно занимательны. А вот Ваши политические экскурсы - зачем Вам они? Если Ваши убеждения таковы, не показывайте их на публике. Зачем публично копаться в собственном носу? Вас подвёл г-н Добров. И зачем только Вы с ним связались? Вы - ранимый человек, и Вам надо быть осторожным в выборе знакомых, которые Вас компрометировали бы... Не торопитесь!

Comment: это участь полуграмотных бегемотусов: не читая произведений, с вучёным видом знатока что-то там изрекать :)

Забавно, что "пасквиль на казачество" в 30-е годы за рубежом воспринимался как "антисоветская повесть" )). 

В чём разница между человеком и бегемотом? Человек умеет мыслить и читать, а бегемот - не умеет)

Comment: Дерзкий, сливай уже свою заезженную пластинку. 
Ты думаешь, я хоть на секунду поверил, что ты - Жиганец? 
Он и прохиндей, но с ним спорить интересно.

Comment: Для сведения спорящих : вопрос авторства ТД меня не волнует.  
Аккаунтов, кроме Дерзкого grumanta, не имел и не имею.  
Жду интересных вопросов, которых пока нет.  
"Поднятую целину" много раз читал в юности, но с тех пор не перечитывал. Может, стоит сравнить впечатления - тогда и сейчас?

Comment: Вопросы по какой тематике Вас интересуют?.. Перечитывать ПЦ не стоит. Перечитывать надо то, к чему душа тянет: вот шевельнулось что-то в сердце, протягиваешь руку к книжному шкафу, берёшь томик и - погружа-а-а-ешься. (Но поэтичность текстов Шолохова магнетизирует - в этом @Сидоров-Жиганец прав. Странно, что умея ценить поэзию в прозе, он не умеет ценить поэзию в человеческих отношениях, допуская грубые намёки в отношении товарищей по "Русскому языку": "... а бегемот - не умеет". Ну что-о-о это? Надо воспитывать в себе не только внутреннюю интеллигентность, но и внешнюю. Не помешает это!).